# Keter delete all image updated in the server when deploy a new version

Tags: file, yesod, keter

I have a project in yesod to load image into a `static / image` directory. The problem is that when implementing a new version on the production server all the images are lost because the temp folder is removed; My question is how to define external paths to add images, I try whit this but don't work

```
uploadDirectory :: FilePath
uploadDirectory = ".." </> "pdf"
```

Or how to prevent keter from creating a new temporary folder each time that deploy a new version

Comment: You'd need to specify the location as outside of the keter temporary dictionary. The same will happen if you are deploying with SQLite and locating the DB in your tmp folder. As to how to define the path I'd use an absolute path.

Comment: @Tehnix could you give and example because I'm try with `uploadDirectory = "/home" </> "pys" </> "Yesod" </> "pdf"` but don't work